# Graph theory and tree company

Tags: graph-theory, trees, extremal-graph-theory

I appreciate anyone who answer this question and I anyone who design appropriate graph.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything? For instance, have you checked the special cases of three investors (three trees to check) or four investors (fifteen trees to check, but less if some $x_i$ are equal) to see if any patterns emerge?

Comment: In first glance I think the answer is X1_X2_..._Xn if X1>X2>...>Xn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the following.

It is clear that for a tree $T$ $\min_i f_i(T)=\min {(i,j)\in E(T): X_i+\frac {X_i}{X_i+X_j}}$, where $E(T)$ is the set of edges of the tree $T$. Let $X_1\le X_2\le\dots X_n$. Then $\min_i f_i(T)\le X_1+\frac {X_1}{X_1+X_2}$, and the maximum is reached when the nodes corresponding to 1th and the 2nd invectors are connected by an edge.